# In spring boot JPA how to delete child records using parent record field value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I need to delete LastTransactionServiceAmount(child) records which have LastTransaction(parent) object's msisdn value equal to certain value.
**LastTransactionServiceAmount.java**

```
@Entity
public class LastTransactionServiceAmount {

private long lastTransactionServiceAmountId;

private LastTransaction lastTransaction;

private int serviceId;

private long amount;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lastTransactionId")
public LastTransaction getLastTransaction() {
    return lastTransaction;
  }

}
```

**LastTransaction.java**

```
@Entity
public class LastTransaction {

private long lastTransactionId;

private long transactionId;

private long tariffId;

private long taxId;

private int planId;

private String msisdn;

private Date dateTime;

private String channel;

private Set<LastTransactionServiceAmount> lastTransactionServiceAmounts;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lastTransaction")
public Set<LastTransactionServiceAmount> getLastTransactionServiceAmounts() {
    return lastTransactionServiceAmounts;
}

}
```

**LastTransactionServiceAmountRepo.java**

```
public interface LastTransactionServiceAmountRepo extends 
CrudRepository<LastTransactionServiceAmount, Long> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM LastTransactionServiceAmount lts WHERE lts.lastTransaction.msisdn = ?1")
void deleteByMsisdn(String msisdn);

}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177429/1811771](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177429/1811771) this can help you. `orphanRemoval = true` this is the key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JpaRepository delete child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175976/jparepository-delete-child-elements)